# shp2pgsql special characters Error

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

sorry it's google translate
An error occurred while importing data into PostGIS using shp2pgsql.
Among multiple shp files, an error occurs only in data with "" special characters.

[image]

The command I used is this

```
shp2pgsql -s 3857 -W UTF-8 -I -c -g the_geom C:\data\vector01.shp test_tb | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -d dbname
```

But when I run it with shp2pgsql-gui.exe, there is no problem

Comment: Assuming you've been able to make the conversion using the GUI version, this might make a good bug report (after you create a minimal reproducible example)-- or is there a reason you can't use the GUI version?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you run command line tools, enclose your filename in double quotes, like this:

```
shp2pgsql -s 3857 -W UTF-8 -I -c -g the_geom "C:\data\vector01.shp" test_tb | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -d dbname
```